# How can I get Ubuntu 14.04 back to pure Unity?

Tags: 14.04, package-management, kubuntu

I installed kubuntu-desktop and that can't be removed, since it is a metapackage.

All of the commands I have seen do not work, including ones that use aptitude and ones that simply state the packages to be removed via apt-get.

How can I make my kubuntu-desktop be completely removed in the latest version Ubuntu 14.04?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest that you freshly reinstall Ubuntu 14.04.  But first backup for you files and other things.

Comment: Thank you, but I think there has to be some other better way getting rid of it. Is there a place with a list of the packages kubuntu-desktop installs?

Comment: Yes there is. Go to the software center>History>Installations. You'll get day to day detailed history there. Uninstall the unwanted packages.